# mmap start failing after n runs

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mmap

I have a problem with mmap. It worked fine for some time, but after 7 or 8 runs it started to fail on 2 instances of virtualized Linux.
I really don't how to fix it.

```
int shm_m = shm_open("/sharedMemory", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0644);
ftruncate(shm_m, sizeof(int) * 3);
int *shared_ints;
if ((shared_ints = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int) * 3, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
     MAP_SHARED, shm_m, 0)) == (void *)-1)
{
    printf("Memory mapping failed\n");
    return 1;
}
shared_ints[0] = 1;
// Molo serfs
shared_ints[1] = 0;
// Molo hackers
shared_ints[2] = 0;
```

Comment: You should print the error, for example with: `perror("mmap");`

Comment: once you execute the posted code, there exists a node, "/sharedMemory" in your file system.  That node is opened 'create' and 'exclusive'  And it does not go away when your program exits.  Your program, before exiting needs to call `int shm_unlink( /sharedMemory");`

Comment: before calling: `shm_unlink()`, should call: `int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);` with the appropriate parameters

Comment: the posted code will not tell you what actually went wrong.  The code needs to 'always' check the returned values from system functions for any error indication.  If any error indication the call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: I'm unlinking in the end but Is it possible that I caused this error by interrupting execution with ctrl-c?

Comment: That information should have been included in the posted code AND the fact that you use `ctrl-c` to exit the program.    As it is, that node is actually created/visible in your file system, so you can browse your file system to see if it is still there.  If still there then it needs to be deleted

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help

Comment: There's a minimum limit to the amount that you can allocate with `mmap()`. It's usually `PAGE_SIZE * 4`.